# Arch Linux lost network in VirtualBox VM after host hibernation

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox, hibernate, antergos

For some reasons I still need Windows, so I've an Arch Linux (AntergOS) VM running in VirtualBox on Windows 10 Pro. To save energy, I put the host in hibernate at night. After starting from hibernate, the Arch-VM lost its network connection. The adapter even has no IP. I tried re-enabling on the host and VM, didn't work. Only restarting the whole VM helps. The network on the host itself works fine.

A research suggests to use bridged network instead of NAT. That's what I'm already using: Bridged network directly to my Realtek LAN-Controller of the mainboard. What can I do to fix this annoying issue?

Comment: The guest OS losing connection would be as expected since the host OS network card would be in a suspended state to preserve energy.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes, but with the host I have no issues. Instantly after re-starting from hibernation, network and internet access is present. However, the VM doesn't get its network back. It seems permanently gone there. Also after waiting for a few minutes, no network connection is present.

Comment: Yes, the guest machine would not see the host machine going into hibernation state. It would just see the network connection as lost and wouldn't re-initialise.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a [reopened bug](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14374) in VirtualBox. You could try restarting the network interface (or service) on your guest OS after waking up in the meantime.

Comment: Looks like Virtualbox is abandonware. It's 2022 and this is still happening